# How do I get the difference of time in human readable format with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, time, laravel-5

I want to display the difference between the current date and time with the one stored in the `updated_at` column. However, I want it to be human-friendly like:

```
53 mins ago
2 hours ago
3 days ago
```

Is there a function out there that I could use to make it easier?

To be sure that you understand me, let's say I have a column (`updated_at`) in my database which is equal to `2015-06-22 20:00:03` and the current time is `20:00:28`. Then I'd like to see:

```
25 mins ago
```

When it's higher than 59 minutes, I want to show only hours and when it's higher than 24 hours I'd like to see how many days ago.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/ozh/8169202) (found on google)

Comment: Look at the DateTime class and the diff method [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: You could use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/), it comes with Laravel.

Comment: huh...not at all, I was asking about a specific and existing function to get diff. of time IN laravel5.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376854/is-this-question-really-too-broad)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates using Carbon and Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39508963) and/or [Carbon Difference in Time between two Dates in hh:mm:ss format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33575239) (taken from the duplicates listed prior to the question being reopened for the second time).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

By default, Eloquent converts `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). So if you are fetching the data using Eloquent, then you can do it as below.

```
$object->updated_at->diffForHumans();
```

If you want to customize the fields that will be mutated automatically, then within your model, you can customize them as you wish.

```
// Carbon instance fields
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, you do NOT need to add 'created_at' and 'updated_at' to the $dates array as they are automatically added. To override this and remove them, set $timestamps property to false

Comment: This solution is correct and still applicable to Laravel 10, thank you Burak

Answer (score 11):

incase of the date is in a string format, use laravel Carbon;
e.g,

```
 {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($on_revision->assignment->deadline)->diffForhumans() }}
```

Notice how I wrap my string in the carbon::parse()

Answer (score 1):

```
function timeDiff($firstTime, $lastTime): string
{
    $firstTime = strtotime($firstTime);
    $lastTime = strtotime($lastTime);

    $difference = $lastTime - $firstTime;

    $data['years'] = abs(floor($difference / 31536000));
    $data['days'] = abs(floor(($difference - ($data['years'] * 31536000)) / 86400));
    $data['hours'] = abs(floor(($difference - ($data['years'] * 31536000) - ($data['days'] * 86400)) / 3600));
    $data['minutes'] = abs(floor(($difference - ($data['years'] * 31536000) - ($data['days'] * 86400) - ($data['hours'] * 3600)) / 60));

    $timeString = '';

    if ($data['years'] > 0) {
        $timeString .= $data['years'] . " Years, ";
    }

    if ($data['days'] > 0) {
        $timeString .= $data['days'] . " Days, ";
    }

    if ($data['hours'] > 0) {
        $timeString .= $data['hours'] . " Hours, ";
    }

    if ($data['minutes'] > 0) {
        $timeString .= $data['minutes'] . " Minutes";
    }

    return $timeString;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).