# How to find difference between two timestamps in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, time

I am trying to compare and find difference between two timestamps. So, this is what I have done.

```
    $add_time = config('constant.time'); //Adding 5 minutes
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($approval->updated_at . '+'.$add_time.' minutes')); //2018-06-09 06:11:13

    $now  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // //2018-06-09 06:42:27


    if($now > $time)
    {
     print_r("Time working")
    }else {
           print_r("Not Working")
          }

    $diff = $now - $time; //Throws Error
```

So, this comparison is working for me. But, when I try to find the difference between these two times, I get an error saying

```
"A non well formed numeric value encountered"
```

How can I find the difference between these two timestamps?

Comment: what is the output of $time here?

Comment: Added the outputs.

Comment: Do I need to point out that you can add `$add_time * 60` to a timestamp to add $add_time minutes to it and save yourself a strtotime call?

Comment: Actually, the $time is bringing correct timestamp with added 5 minutes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575239/carbon-difference-in-time-between-two-dates-in-hhmmss-format

Comment: Thanks for your help.