# Calculate difference between two dates using Carbon and Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

Does anyone know how to pass a given variable instead the Carbon's default parameters ?

The documentation of Carbon says:

```
// CARBON SAMPLE

$dtToronto = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 1, 1, 'America/Toronto');
$dtVancouver = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 1, 1, 'America/Vancouver');
echo $dtVancouver->diffInHours($dtToronto); // 3
```

And i want to do something like this in my controller:

```
  // EXAMPLE

  $date = "2016-09-16 11:00:00";
  $datework = Carbon::createFromDate($date);
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $testdate = $datework->diffInDays($now);
```

And retrieving that on a Blade template

```
  // VIEW ON BLADE

  <td> {{ $testdate }} </td>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to explain. Do you get any errors? Does it show the wrong values? I think your solution will be using `new Carbon($date)` instead of `Carbon::createFromDate($date)`.

Comment: Try With: `Carbon::parseDate($date);` insted of `createFromDate`

Comment: So i'm trying to calculate it via Blade: `<td>{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($work['date']) }}</td>` but i have this error: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Carbon\Carbon::diffInDays() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, string given`. So i have the variable $work['date'] that is a result from the Model query and not a Carbon Object...

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You are not following the example from the [Carbon Documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). The method `Carbon::createFromDate()` expects 4 parameters: *year*, *month*, *day* and *timezone*. And you are trying to pass a formatted date string.

If you want to create a Carbon object from a formatted date string you can use the constructor of the class just like this:

```
$date = "2016-09-17 11:00:00";
$datework = new Carbon($date);
```

Or you can use the static `Carbon::parse()` method:

```
$date = "2016-09-17 11:00:00";
$datework = Carbon::parse($date);
```

For your purposes you can use the this full example:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2016-09-17 11:00:00');
$now = Carbon::now();

$diff = $date->diffInDays($now);
```

And then in your Blade template:

```
<td> {{ $diff }} </td>
```

Comment: Well after many tries, this is the only way that works:     `<td> <!--  {{ $datework = Carbon\Carbon::parse($work['date']) }} {{ $now = Carbon\Carbon::now() }} // for this --> {{ $diff = $datework->diffForHumans($now) }} </td>` It's all calculate directely the view layer, adding html comments code to remove the Blade output...

Comment: @MarcoFacc it's highly preferable to not do those calculations in the view template.

Comment: ideally i want to calculate these dates inside his own controller, but the information that i need are retrieved on the view layer via foreach cycle on the $work array. I'm still trying to make something more clean, and put it inside the controller but for now i haven't found any better solution.

Comment: Carbon has built in Comparison, there's no need to go back to PHP.

Comment: That's exactly what's shown in the example - one of the Carbon's built in difference methods - `diffInDays()`

Comment: FYI, Carbon's diffInX() methods default to now, so no need to specify if that's when you're comparing to.

Comment: This does not include the start date. I want to get the count in days from start to end like date 16-25 I think return should be 10 days. But returning 9 days.

Answer (score 16):

Blade Template

A shorter code

```
{{ $diff = Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->last_updated)->diffForHumans() }}
```

Result : 6 minutes ago

Comment: Is it possible to use if condition somehow. For example if ($diff > 10 ) print  $diff else print   'short time ammount'

Comment: @wajih, not that i'm aware of but that's a good question, i do sometimes feel the need for something like that too.

Answer (score 7):

You code can be cleaned up and have the commented out code removed by doing:

```
<td>{{ $diff = Carbon\Carbon::parse($work['date'])->diffForHumans(Carbon\Carbon::now()) }} </td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Shortest way

We can directly write it in blade

```
<span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $start_date )->diffInDays( $end_date ) }}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Carbon means you do not need to mix PHP Datetime and Carbon.
Once you have the datetime as a Carbon, simply do this...

`$comparisonTimeAsCarbon->diffAsCarbonInterval($theOtherTimeAsCarbon)`

You can change `diffAsCarbonInterval` to `diffAsSeconds`, `diffAsMinutes` and many more.

`diffForHumans` is one of my faves.

Or, choose your own format with...

`$comparisonTimeAsCarbon->diff($theOtherTimeAsCarbon)->format('%I:%S')`

Carbon will even let you add text instead of a Carbon time, but, I recommend you use Carbon before you parse it, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on a Blade template directly:

```
{{ (Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->created_at))->diffInDays(Carbon\Carbon::now()) }}
```