# Check the date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, time

I would like to make a script that checks the date.

If the given date is today: **return true** else .... **return false**.

I have something like that.

```
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->end_time);
    $date = Carbon::createFromDate($end->year, $end->month, $end->day, 'Europe/Warsaw');

    if($date->diffInDays() == 0){
        // It's today.
        return true;
    }
```

(I need to have this time conversion because I'm from Poland and I have other time)

However, I do not know why this does not work.

```
if($date->diffInDays() == 0){
    // It's today.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you log some values and see? like the value of $date->diffInDays()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two dates using Carbon and Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php)
There you can find all informations needed to solve your pproblems