# calculate years beetwen two dates laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have mySQL database table field :

```
description
unit
start_date
end_date
```

for example :

start_date : 05-07-2019

end_date : 10-08-2021

how I calculate number of years?

Comment: Have you looked into Carbon. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with carbon,

```
use Carbon\Carbon;


$startDate = Carbon::parse('05-07-2019'); 
$endDate = Carbon::parse('10-08-2021'); 
$diff = $startDate->diffInYears($endDate);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime("05-07-2019");
 $datetime2 = new DateTime("10-08-2021");
 $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, ' 
               .$difference->m.' months, ' 
               .$difference->d.' days';
```

Output will be

```
Difference: 2 years, 1 months, 5 days
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use date_diff, in your example its will return 1.

```
$start_date = date_create("05-07-2019");
$end_date = date_create("10-08-2021");
$diff = date_diff($start_date, $end_date);
echo $diff->y;
```