# Laravel carbon get year month format form two date

Tags: php, laravel

I have store from_date and to_date in the database with MySQL DATE column type.
How can I get date difference between from_date and to_date in format ..eg 1 Year 2 Months

```
2018-01-05
2019-02-22

2 Year 1 Month
```

Comment: Hope you're looking for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  $datetime1 = new DateTime("2018-01-05");
  $datetime2 = new DateTime("2019-02-22");
  $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo !empty($difference->y) ? $difference->y.' Year ':'';
  echo !empty($difference->m) ? $difference->m.' Month ':'';
```

The output will be

```
   1 Year 1 Month
```

In carbon way

```
 use Carbon\Carbon;

 $startDate = Carbon::parse('2018-01-05'); 
 $endDate = Carbon::parse('2019-02-22'); 
 $diff = $startDate->diffInYears($endDate);
 $diffs = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);

 echo $diff;
 echo $diffs;
```