# Difference between two dates in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date

I have a problem with difference between two days.

How is it possible to get number of days?

Here is my code,

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day"));
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 day"));
```

Comment: have a look at the docs for date_diff() in php manual. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Which type output you want?

Comment: Raw PHP will work, but this is the Laravel way to do it with Carbon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519892/3103434

Answer (score 0):

I use Pure PHP :

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day"));
$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 day"));
$diff = abs(strtotime($start) - strtotime($end));
$days = floor($diff/60/60/24);
$total = sprintf("%d days\n", $days);
return $total; // 6 days
```