# I need to get the interval between two dates, one is from system date, and one is from the database

Tags: php, html, laravel, date, php-carbon

So, I had to find an interval between two dates, one is from system time, and one is from the database. First problem is, I used `get()` so it returns an array from the database and I have absolutely no idea on how to work on it. Can anyone tell me what is the best way to deal with this? I just need to get the number of days between `$tenggat` and `$curdate`.

```
public function tower_kecamatan(Request $r){
        $kode_kecamatan = $r->kode_kecamatan;
        $region = DB::table('region')
                    ->where('kode_kecamatan',$kode_kecamatan)->first();
        $data = DB::table('tower')
        ->leftJoin("perusahaan","perusahaan.tower_id","=","tower.tower_id")
        ->select('tower.*','perusahaan.*')
                ->where('kode_kecamatan', $kode_kecamatan)->get();
        $tenggat = DB::table('tower')
        ->select('tower.tenggat_izin')->get();
        $curdate = Carbon::now();        
    
        return view('tower_kecamatan', compact('region','data','tenggat'));
    }
```

Comment: the "best" way is to use eloquent models and add the date attribute to the "Date mutators" (read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators )...then you get to operate on carbon instances directly

Comment: you may want to check [Carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade)

Answer (score 0):

```
$tenggat = DB::table('tower')->select('tower.tenggat_izin')->get();
```

return the collection of objects, and you need just first one.

```
$rows = DB::table('tower')->select('tower.tenggat_izin')->get();
$tenggat = $rows[0]; 
$diff = Carbon::now()->diffInDays(Carbon::parse($tenggat->tenggat_izin));
$diff2 = Carbon::parse($tenggat->tenggat_izin)->diffInDays(Carbon::now();
```

I am not sure about field naming, but this code returns the diff in days between the current date and `tenggat_izin` field from table `tower`

It's not a good way, as said above use eloquent, and it will be much easier