# How do i Convert timestamp into Human readable format (1 month ago)

Tags: php, timestamp, yii2-advanced-app, laravel-5.4

I am using Carbon Api extension in my Yii2 Advanced Application project

My code is like below.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time=time();
$y = date("Y",$time); //Year eg.2017
$n = date("n",$time); //Month eg.4
$j = date("j",$time); //Day eg.4
$h = date("G",$time); //Hour eg.10 (24 Hour format)
$i = date("i",$time); //Minute eg.15
$s = date("s",$time); //Socond eg.27
$carbon_time = Carbon::create($y,$n,$j,$h,$i,$s);
$parsed_time=Carbon::parse($carbon_time);
echo $parsed_time->diffForHumans(); //Carbon Api object
```

How do I Shorten this above code..?

$carbon_time and $parsed_time will give the output like --> 2017-04-04 10:15:27

I'm expecting to get this as output --> "1 second ago"

Comment: Does this work?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30992170/6720181

Comment: I have used this method in my **Laravel project** and it worked. But i'm trying to get the same in my  yii2 project but it's not working. Then i've tried the above mentioned method but it's too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon is just an extension of the \DateTime Object, so you can do this.

```
$dateTime = new Carbon('-1 month', new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $dateTime->diffForHumans();
```

If you have a timestamp you can do this

```
$dateTime = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(
    $myTimestamp,
    new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')
);
echo $dateTime->diffForHumans();
```

Comment: Thanks @Augwa this works for me but i'm not expecting this,I need to convert the timestamp that i've stored in the database when i save a new Post in to the database.

Comment: Yes i'm storing the Unix timestamp.